# Preventing an android app being cloned by an app cloner

Tags: android

Created an app that used the device's uniqueID which is fetched by the following code snippet

```
String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

When the user tries to clone the app by app cloner, then it creates a different deviceID and the app is not allowed to work

Is there any way to make our app non clonable
or

Any possible way to have the same deviceId even if the app instance is cloned?

Is there any way to find out whether the app is running in a cloned instance?

Comment: there is no way to completely prevent cloning. Hackers will always find a way.

Comment: @CommonsWare i there any workaround to prevent this?

Comment: Tried all possible ways! but no luck!!

Answer (score 8):

Applications like Cloner usually change your application's package name so you can retrieve package name and check if it is changed or not.

```
if (!context.getPackageName().equals("your.package.name")){
    // close the app or do whatever
}
```

Also they usually sign cloned apk so the signature might be different from yours, you can check if signature is changed or not. I usually use this function:

```
@SuppressLint("PackageManagerGetSignatures")
public static int getCertificateValue(Context ctx){
    try {
        Signature[] signatures = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            try {
                signatures = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES).signingInfo.getApkContentsSigners();
            }catch (Throwable ignored){}
        }
        if (signatures == null){
            signatures = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
        }
        int value = 1;

        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            value *= signature.hashCode();
        }
        return value;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

public static boolean checkCertificate(Context ctx, int trustedValue){
    return getCertificateValue(ctx) == trustedValue;
}
```

Before releasing your app call `getCertificateValue(context)` and write down the value and alongside with package name, check if that value matches the value that you get in runtime.

PS: as @vladyslav-matviienko said hackers will always find a way so try to make cloning harder by running some obfuscations on hardcoded package name and that value. Also try to tangle and spread these kind of logics all around the source code.

Comment: Class SigningInfo not found exception

Comment: getCertificateValue(context) value is changed when we install app from play store
Is there any solution for that ?

Comment: @Rishabh play store resigns your apk by default, you can release a beta with a Log inside it, write that down using logcat and then upload another version with that. Also the function I put here was an example, you can search for othet methods as well.

Comment: Have to try to implement that code on production? 

That beta release and production release have same version

I suffer a lot last time to upload a build on production and my 2 lakh plus user is impact and not able to open app.

Not able to take risk now !

Please let me know your experience on it.

Comment: The signature check is not working (not valid) on the apps cloned by App Cloner. The Clone copies have the same signature matching the original Playstore one. Check signature is more effective in detecting clone copies. 

Link to the app cloner: https://appcloner.app/

Answer (score 1):

I found a story in [proandroiddev](https://proandroiddev.com/preventing-android-app-cloning-e3194269bcfa) by [Siddhant Panhalkar](https://medium.com/@siddhantpanhalkar) and with some minor changes it's work perfectly in Mi device I did checked in Mi phones **default Dual apps** and some third party apps from playstore and it prevents from cloning (means not working properly after clone).

```
private const val APP_PACKAGE_DOT_COUNT = 3 // number of dots present in package name
private const val DUAL_APP_ID_999 = "999"
private const val DOT = '.'

fun CheckAppCloning(activity: Activity) {
    val path: String = activity.filesDir.getPath()
    if (path.contains(DUAL_APP_ID_999)) {
        killProcess(activity)
    } else {
        val count: Int = getDotCount(path)
        if (count > APP_PACKAGE_DOT_COUNT) {
            killProcess(activity)
        }
    }
}
private fun getDotCount(path: String): Int {
    var count = 0
    for (element in path) {
        if (count > APP_PACKAGE_DOT_COUNT) {
            break
        }
        if (element == DOT) {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count
}

private fun killProcess(context: Activity) {
    context.finish()
    android.os.Process.killProcess( android.os.Process.myPid())
}
```